Navgiation Component nested graph backstack issue with bottom navigation
Navgiation graph skeleton below:
MainActivity
|- RootNav
   |- HomeNavGraph (RootNav's startDestination) (bottom nav tab 1)
      |- HomeFragment (HomeNavGraph's startDestination)
      |- ListFragment
   |- SearchNavGraph (bottom nav tab 2)
      |- SearchFragment (SearchNavGraph startDestination)

Below is the expected backstack:
|            |    |            |    |SearchFragment|    |            |
|            | -> |ListFragment| -> | ListFragment | -> |ListFragment|
|HomeFragment|    |HomeFragment|    | HomeFragment |    |HomeFragment|

Below is the actual backstack:
|            |    |            |    |SearchFragment|    |            |
|            | -> |ListFragment| -> | ListFragment | -> |            |
|HomeFragment|    |HomeFragment|    | HomeFragment |    |HomeFragment|

Situation: When I click the back button on my device when SearchFragment is active, the backstack pops both SearchFragment and ListFragment and shows HomeFragment. However, when I click the bottom nav tab 1 then only SearchFragment is poped and shows ListFragment.
I tried using onBackPressedDispatcher in my NavHostActivity like this:
onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
                override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                    val currentDestination = navController.currentDestination
                    when (currentDestination?.id) {
                        R.id.navGraphSearchFragment -> {
                            navController.navigate(R.id.tabHomeFragment)
                        }

                        else -> {
                            if (!navController.popBackStack()) {
                                finish()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })

Realisation: While the nav_graph backstack is still active onBackPressedDispatcher is never called.
Help: It would be helpful if anyone can explain how I can mimick the same navigation flow I get when I click the bottom nav tab with the device back button press.
